# Would it be possible to write a novel without using the word "The"?

Tags: word-choice

In the novel I am writing, the story is told present tense and first person. The themes of the story present some unique points to the style, but something I have noticed as a write the first few chapters, it seems to lack the word THE. Which made me wonder, is it even possible to write a novel the completely lacks the most common word?

Comment: Is there any reason it *wouldn't* be possible? It mostly sounds frustrating to write, and of rather dubious benefit :-/

Comment: (In general, the answer to most "Is it possible to write something where--" questions lies somewhere between "Sure, why not" and "try it and see".)

Comment: Why does this keep getting downvotes? It's a totally fine, on topic question

Comment: @Standback There are things you "can't" do (read: really oughtn't to), like randomly switch POVs or verb tenses without a narrative reason. There are things you can do that are so unreadable that they become self-defeating, like, I dunno, writing a book and then laying it out so it reads bottom-to-top and right-to-left (for readers accustomed to left-to-right). The OP is kind of asking "Would such a book be readable, or would the trick make it pointless?"

Comment: @LaurenIpsum : There are lots of things that are "probably a bad idea." Usually, a good enough author can make them work anyway, *if* they've good cause and sufficient skill. OP isn't asking "is this a good idea",  it's obviously not meant to be one. They're asking "can this be made to work," and the answer there is always "if you've got a good reason for it and you're sufficiently skilled."

Comment: Is this question a hoax? You wrote a "few chapters" in a certain way, and now you ask if it is possible to write in that way. Didn't you just prove yourself that one can?

Comment: @DanielCann: If it were off-topic, I would vote to close it :-P It offers an arbitrary goal, without laying out a motivation or detailing what practical problem OP has trying to do what he's aiming at. And please remember: there is **nothing wrong** with downvoting questions, when that's your opinion. Voting questions up *and* down is what shapes the nature of the site.

Comment: @what Sure, the chapters are written, but are they any good? Yes, it's possible to write several chapters where you pop in and out of characters' heads arbitrarily, change tenses randomly, and generally copy the worst facets of *My Immortal,* but just because it's physically written doesn't mean it's readable. The real upshot is that we here can't know if it's possible because we haven't read what the OP has written.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Art isn't just about "good". Art is about *attempting* – and growing in the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a novel, can I do \[this or that\]?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/25819/writing-a-novel-can-i-do-this-or-that)

Comment: Sure. Just write it in a language that doesn't spell any of its words by the letter sequence "T", "H", "E".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're talking about what is called **constrained writing.** Here is a [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing). Constrained writing is where you purposefully constrain yourselves by not allowing yourself to do certain things. For example, Lauren Ipsum's example in her answer of *writing a book without using E* is what is called a **lipogram.** This is where a certain letter of the alphabet (or couple!) are not used during a piece of writing.

These techniques of constrained writing are often used in poetry, though they can slip everywhere. Lauren's answer features a book which I was going to include in my answer, but I wasn't here first. That book is proof that a lipogram can be achieved in a very long piece of work. In fact, I remember that a year ago in my England class we were tasked to rewrite the entire first page of *nineteen-eighty-four* by *George Orwell* without using the letter E.

I think it's certainly possible. Omitting 'the' would be a form of constrained writing. If you're trying to do this... well, good luck!

Comment: that is a bloody fascinating link. I had no idea people played such writing games. I'm familiar with drabbles, double-drabbles, acrostics, etc. but not some of the lettered ones. The *Sherlock* fandom also writes "221b" fics, in which either the whole story or each section has exactly 221 words and the last word must begin with B.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's really great. You should try doing some of them, because I've found that they can actually be **very** challenging, rewarding and force you to stretch and manipulate the ways you write. @LaurenIpsum

Comment: Actually (almost) every writing is constrained writing! Every novel is constrained by its plot, by its story, and by the ability of its author. We may not think of this as constrained writing, but if you have ever written anything (which you have), you will have experienced the frustrating struggle to stay within the constraints that your characters and plot and your linguistic skills put on you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, someone [wrote a book without using the letter E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsby_(novel)), so by default *the* wasn't used. (according to Wiki, it does slip in three times. Very hard to avoid. Plus technically it's on the cover.) Whether the book is any good is an exercise left to the reader.

I suppose it would be fun to do as a challenge, but then the challenge is "avoiding the letter" and not "telling the best story possible using the best words for the job." So it depends on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the book "Gadsby" has no E's (except in the title obviously) yet it has over 50,000 words. So yes, it is possible to write a book without the word "the". *Not saying it's easy*

Comment: Actually, actually, there's a couple of "the"s and an "officer" that slipped through into publishing. They're easily found in the transcription on [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/47342/47342-h/47342-h.htm); also see the transcriber's notes at the end there. With the convenience of today's software it would be easy to avoid such slip-ups, so however hard it is, it's easier now then it was when Gadsby was written.

Comment: The above is fascinating. Such constraints could be easily implemented with AI novels. But would anything interesting be produced? Aside from free verse, poetry, too, is constrained, and much of its beauty comes from those constraints.

Answer (score -3):

No.
It is entirely impossible to write a novel without using the word 'the'.
I cannot even write that previous sentence without using that word, so I can say unequivocally that it is completely 100% impossible.

I'm attempting to balance the answers here since so many (incorrectly) believe it is possible.

**Little-known fact:**

Ernest Hemingway attempted to do this very thing when he wrote, [The Old Man & The Sea -- amazon link](http://amzn.to/2pwZ5Lz) (originally titled : Old Man & Sea) and he failed.
He used the word 'the' only 17 times in the entire book.  Read it and see.
Astonishing!

**Very Difficult, But I Just Completed It**

*Discombobulated*

Also, I recently finished an entire novel without using the word discombobulated and I'm quite proud.  98.3% of all novels include the word discombobulated, just as this very post does.  It was difficult to write this post without using the word so I went ahead and did so.

Comment: um, so if the *Gadsby* writer had been a little more meticulous or had a S/R function and caught the three *the*s which sneaked by, would we all have disappeared up our own existence?

Comment: Sorry, dear. I really really think you're wrong. I save my extremely rare DVs for those very few times when I think someone has genuinely posted a wrong answer. Congrats, baby. ;)

Comment: Rewrite your second sentence as "It is entirely impossible to write a novel without any instances of that word," and it omits forbidden words entirely. So that's not a very good demonstration of impossibility, is it? Note that this comment also doesn't contain forbidden words. It's pretty easy, really.